# Read/Retrieve emails from Outlook (Office 365) account

Tags: c#, outlook, office365

I set up my outlook Office 365 account and I want to retrieve the emails from my outlook mailbox, earlier we were using Exchange Service in our code, but now we can't use the Exchange service anymore due to EWS his no longer available in microsoft.

Could you please help me how can I retrieve my emails in outlook office 365 account.

I am attaching a sample code that I have created but I am not able to read the emails.

In the below code, i tried to retrieve email through IMAP4 protocol server.
When i run the code, i get this error - ReceiveOutlookMail.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

```
class Program
{
    // Generate an unqiue email file name based on date time
    static string _generateFileName(int sequence)
    {
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        return string.Format("{0}-{1:000}-{2:000}.eml",
            currentDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", new CultureInfo("en-US")),
            currentDateTime.Millisecond,
            sequence);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a folder named "inbox" under current directory
            // to save the email retrieved.
            string localInbox = string.Format("{0}\\inbox", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            // If the folder is not existed, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(localInbox))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(localInbox);
            }

            // Hotmail/MSN IMAP4 server is "imap-mail.outlook.com"
            //MailServer oServer = new MailServer("imap-server-name",
             //   "liveid@hotmail.com", "yourpassword", ServerProtocol.Imap4);

            // For office 365 user, please change server to:
            MailServer oServer = new MailServer("imap-server-name",
                "test@gmail.com", "password", ServerProtocol.Imap4);

            // Enable SSL connection.
            oServer.SSLConnection = true;

            // Set 993 SSL port
            oServer.Port = 993;

            MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");
            oClient.Connect(oServer);

            // retrieve unread/new email only
            oClient.GetMailInfosParam.Reset();
            oClient.GetMailInfosParam.GetMailInfosOptions = GetMailInfosOptionType.NewOnly;

            MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
            Console.WriteLine("Total {0} unread email(s)\r\n", infos.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
            {
                MailInfo info = infos[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                    info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL);

                // Receive email from IMAP4 server
                Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

                Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);

                // Generate an unqiue email file name based on date time.
                string fileName = _generateFileName(i + 1);
                string fullPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", localInbox, fileName);

                // Save email to local disk
                oMail.SaveAs(fullPath, true);

                // mark unread email as read, next time this email won't be retrieved again
                if (!info.Read)
                {
                    oClient.MarkAsRead(info, true);
                }

                // if you don't want to leave a copy on server, please use
                // oClient.Delete(info);
                // instead of MarkAsRead
            }

            // Quit and expunge emails marked as deleted from IMAP4 server.
            oClient.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
        }
        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: See following : https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=1

Comment: @jdweng yes, I took the code from this link only, When I run the code, I get this error message - "A socket operation failed because the destination host was down"

Comment: Does code work from your home PC?  Do it fail only in your company network?  I think it may be a port number issue.  Check with your MIS the port number.  Some companies use different port numbers.  You may have a firewall or virus checker that is blocking the port.  Also verify the URL for the server is correct.

Comment: EWS is very much available and supported. They just said they would invest in new features in Graph. But EWS is still there, and MS itself uses it internally for some features (such as OOF)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I agree, but they removed basic authentication from EWS. So, how can we perform Authentication when we are using EWS?

Comment: They did not (it can be enabled on the per tenant basis). And it is not EWS specific. You authenticate using access tokens.